# What is causing this crash in NSUserDefaults?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, nsuserdefaults

We see a sporadic crash in our user base, during a routine read from `NSUserDefaults`. The overwhelming majority of users don't experience this problem, and those that do aren't running any particular version of iOS. It seems to have appeared only since we started deploying with Xcode 9.1.

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE 0x000000016efe3fc0

Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libswiftCore.dylib             0x101816d4c @objc _NSContiguousString.length() + 5720
1  CoreFoundation                 0x181e2a168 CFStringCompareWithOptionsAndLocale + 96
2  Foundation                     0x1828602fc -[NSString isEqualToString:] + 76
3  CoreFoundation                 0x181e19558 CFEqual + 596
4  CoreFoundation                 0x181e15414 CFBasicHashFindBucket + 344
5  CoreFoundation                 0x181e152a0 CFDictionaryGetValue + 224
6  CoreFoundation                 0x181ef0c74 -[CFPrefsSearchListSource alreadylocked_copyValueForKey:] + 108
7  CoreFoundation                 0x181f8f224 -[CFPrefsSource copyValueForKey:] + 64
8  CoreFoundation                 0x181f992c0 __76-[_CFXPreferences copyAppValueForKey:identifier:container:configurationURL:]_block_invoke + 40
9  CoreFoundation                 0x181ef44f0 __108-[_CFXPreferences(SearchListAdditions) withSearchListForIdentifier:container:buttConfigurationURL:perform:]_block_invoke + 268
10 CoreFoundation                 0x181ef3d0c normalizeQuintuplet + 356
11 CoreFoundation                 0x181ef43d8 -[_CFXPreferences(SearchListAdditions) withSearchListForIdentifier:container:buttConfigurationURL:perform:] + 108
12 CoreFoundation                 0x181f99258 -[_CFXPreferences copyAppValueForKey:identifier:container:configurationURL:] + 124
13 CoreFoundation                 0x181f9bbbc _CFPreferencesGetAppBooleanValueWithContainer + 136
14 Foundation                     0x1828517a8 -[NSUserDefaults(NSUserDefaults) boolForKey:] + 112
15 <our code>                     0x100d80750 @objc SettingsPersistence.persistedBool.getter (SettingsPersistence.swift:90)
```

Here's how we retrieve the value (Swift 3, called via Objective C):

```
fileprivate static let PersistedBoolKey = "persistedBool"

public var persistedBool: Bool {
    get {
        return UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: SettingsPersistence.PersistedBoolKey)
    }

    set(newPersistedBool) {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(newPersistedBool, forKey: SettingsPersistence.PersistedBoolKey)
    }
}
```

I thought it might be a thread issue, but this occurs on the main thread. Either way, `NSUserDefaults` is documented as completely thread-safe.

This looks to me like a low-level bug in Apple's libraries. What can I do to fix this problem on my end? Who should I report it to? Has anyone else experienced a similar problem?

Thank you!

Comment: As a matter of intrigue, what percentage of your users *are* seeing this crash?

Comment: @JamesWebster We have a 99.7% crash free rate, and we have a few other major crash types as well. (According to Crashlytics.)

Comment: Before you worry about this issue too much, I suggest you weigh up the effort it will take to find and fix compared to the benefit provided to <0.3% of your users. This is one of those issues that I would keep an eye on, but not actively work on unless it started to become a bigger problem.

Comment: I see a whitespace between `SettingsPersistence.` and `PersistedBoolKey` in the get statement. Have you checked that?

Comment: @Oxthor thanks, it was an error introduced by my efforts to scrub sensitive information from the code. It doesn't exist in the source. I've removed it.

Comment: That stack trace, to me, suggests the problem is an over-release of `SettingsPersistence.PersistedBoolKey`. Is that even a little likely? (It feels very unlikely, but it's what the stack trace is suggesting.) I really can't think of a way that it's possible in pure Swift to cause that to happen, but maybe if you're doing anything strange with the key in CoreFoundation? (Now I'm really reaching…)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This crash has disappeared ever since upgrading Xcode to 9.4.1.